# Using std::apply on class method

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, c++20, stdapply

I'm trying to get the following to compile (g++-11.2, C++20), but I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(int, double)>, std::__tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<int, double> >, std::__tuple_element_t<1, std::tuple<int, double> >)'
 1843 |       return std::__invoke(std::forward<_Fn>(__f),
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct Foo
{
    void bar(const int x, const double y) 
    {  
        std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
    }  


    void bar_apply()
    {  
        // fails
        std::apply(std::mem_fn(&Foo::bar), std::tuple<int, double>(1, 5.0));
    }  
};


int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar_apply();
};
```

Comment: `bar` is non-static so you need to pass `this` as an argument

Comment: Perhaps: `std::apply([this](int x, double y) { return bar(x,y); }, std::tuple<int, double>(1, 5.0));`

Comment: @AlanBirtles You mean `this->bar` instead of `&Foo::bar`?  If so, doesn't work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That works, but is there a way without creating a lambda?

Comment: I've not used `std::apply` but I'd imagine `std::apply(std::mem_fn(&Foo::bar), std::make_tuple(this, 1, 5.0))` will work

Comment: ...or `std::apply(std::mem_fn(&Foo::bar), std::tuple<Foo*, int, double>(this, 1, 5.0));`

Comment: Yes, these answers works.  If you write an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat older question, but anyways: Creating an overload `bar(const std::tuple<int, double>&)`  might also be a straight forward option.

Comment: @nick I can't remember why exactly I asked, but it seems like the spirit of the question was to use `apply`, perhaps because we cannot modify `bar`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend using C++20 [`bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front), which is more lightweight and intuitive. Just like its name, member functions require a specific class object to invoke, so you need to *bind* `this` pointer to `Foo::bar`.

```
void bar_apply()
{  
  std::apply(std::bind_front(&Foo::bar, this), std::tuple<int, double>(1, 5.0));
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/xE41b4f47)

Comment: This is nice, but I've heard the `std::bind` doesn't have optimal performance.  Do you know if that's the same story with `std::bind_front`?

Comment: One of the purposes of the introduction of `std::bind_front` is to solve the problem of insufficient performance of `std::bind`. Therefore, it is more lightweight and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

`std::mem_fn(&Foo::bar)` does not store the instance of `Foo` like a capturing lambda would do:

```
std::apply([this](int x, double y) { return bar(x,y); },
           std::tuple<int, double>(1, 5.0));
```

You therefore need to supply the instance when calling the `mem_fn` object:

```
std::apply(std::mem_fn(&Foo::bar), std::tuple<Foo*, int, double>(this, 1, 5.0));
```

or simpler, using `make_tuple`:

```
std::apply(std::mem_fn(&Foo::bar), std::make_tuple(this, 1, 5.0));
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you need an instance to call the member function. This you can deliver to `std::apply` by wrapping the function call to a lambda expression or via tuple arguments.

However, I would suggest [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke), which is more apt to this task. By this way, no instance wrapping is required.

```
#include <functional> // std::invoke

std::invoke(&Foo::bar, this, 1, 5.0);
```

Comment: `bar(1, 5.0);` would be even simpler in this case :-)

Comment: @JeJo Good point, but the actual use case is that I'm storing the arguments of `bar` in a queue of tuples.